# How to create a type for a class in typescript with all private Methods and properties public

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type for a typescript class with all private properties and methods set public. For the class

```
class C {
    public a: number = 1;
    private x: number = 0;
    private y: number = 0;
    private z: number = 0;
    private m (): {
        // som complex operations
    }
}
```

this type

```
type CP = {
    [Property in keyof C]: C[Property];
}
```

has only property `a`. So I tried

```
type CP = {
    public [Property in keyof C]: C[Property];
}
```

but that is definitely wrong. Is there a solution?

And yes, the purpose is testing, and yes, I think it should be allowed to test private methods!

Comment: typescript private properties and methods are not really private, as there's no such thing as 'private' in js. So if you're casting it to `any` or `Object` this should be enough to make them public (for testing purposes only, of course). `(new C() as any).x`. that would obviously put  your static typing in danger of inconsistency, so should never be relied on in production.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Any mapping would be based on `keyof` and type queries (`T[P]`) both of  these don't allow access  to private fields.

Comment: So I continue with the old ```<any>``` trick.